# Recent comic strip - A female PhD, her robot and a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, comics

Can someone help me figure out what comic strip this is?

This is recent.  It is a comic strip and they did this really funny short.

Dr So and So has a robot. She beat Apollo 11 to the moon so the Americans wouldn't claim it. The Apollo astronauts were firing shotguns into the "air" when they landed.

I just can't remember.  It was very clever and funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dr. Connie Radar, PhD](http://connieradar.blogspot.com/). [This article](http://www.space.com/28661-connie-radar-moon-landing-video.html) describes how a short film was made of the episode you were describing.

> The short film "Over the Moon" on Vimeo details the fictional lunar adventures of Dr. Connie Radar. "Over the Moon" chronicle's Radar attempting to stop the first moon landing by a crew of American astronauts. (In this science fiction world, Radar landed on the lunar surface in 1957, well before the 1969 Apollo 11 moon landing.) The 7-minute-video is based on the "Dr. Connie Radar PhD" comic strip and comes complete with a robot and some sleazy astronauts bouncing around and cooking hot dogs. Check out the video in the window below:

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find the comic strip in question on their site, even on [the prior site](http://comicbookfactory.blogspot.com/search/label/webcomic/), which holds some of the earlier strips.

Comment: Could he be thinking of the short film's storyboards? http://comicbookfactory.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/over-moon-storyboard-part-2.html

Comment: It is possible. I was also running into a gap in the strips last night based on tagging, although I searched with different criteria this morning and I don't know that that gap is still there.

Comment: Ah, the gap in the strips is caused by viewing them on the front page. It seems to jump from 015 to 030 in a single bound. If you search for them (top left) by issue number, they're all still on there.